# How to set custom message in Angular component

Tags: html, angular, header

I am trying to send a custom error message to be displayed in the HTMl. Right now, 
my component looks like this :

```
 this.editForm.controls.name.setErrors({"incorrect": true});
 error.headers.get("errorMessageKey"); //this returns the custom message i want to display
```

I am aware that we need to use a boolean to toggle the message in HTML but I am not sure how to implement it.

My HTML looks like this but the message is not showing up :

```
  <small class="form-text text-danger"                   
[hidden]="!editForm.controls.name?.errors?.incorrect"> {{name.incorrect}}
  </small>
```

My question is, how to bind the message and the boolean together so that the message can be displayed in the HTML ?

Comment: You should declare a public variable to hold the error message and show it in `{{}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use this:

```
<small class="form-text text-danger"[hidden]="editForm.get('name').valid"> {{name.incorrect}}
```

Which would then hide the message when the control is valid.

Comment: Well you need to store `error.headers.get("errorMessageKey")` in a variable and then bind that with `{{myError}}` for it to show up. Right now I don't know what `name` even is.

Comment: thanks, that worked. If I wanna set a custom success message, do i just toggle the true to false ?

Comment: @decemberrobot Yup.